# Sound effects for alucination

Tags: sound-effects

Hello everybody !I'm a student of lightning and sound design for theatre and I'm looking for sound effects' websites that could help me to find several sound fx for a person's alucination Can you help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

im assuming you mean hallucination?

Comment: yes !! Sory for my english 

Answer (score 1):

You will find plenty of good advice on this site but please can you give more detail on what you would like to achieve. A hallucination could be interpreted in thousands of different ways.

Context is extremely important, so if you add a little more detail to your request I'm sure you'll find the responses to be very helpful!

Comment: It's a play about a girl that had a car accident and her memory is too foggy and she can't remember big part of her life, so she looks for a woman that is already dead, and when she finds that woman, she's hallucinating. And I want sounds for that moment that she's hallucinating.. Sorry for my english! 

Answer (score 0):

It's not Hallucination but maybe you'll find this useful:

http://cuneimedia.com/arcanum/occult-voices-paranormal-music-recordings-of-unseen-intelligences-1905-2007

occult voices paranormal music recordings of unseen intelligences 1905-2007
Published by Thomas Knoefel und Andreas Fischer Köln
Released by supposé (2007)
Trance Speech and Direct Voice

Answer (score 0):

Is this for theater? Using these live?

Comment: It's a play about a girl that had a car accident and her memory is too foggy and she can't remember big part of her life, so she looks for a woman that is already dead, and when she finds that woman, she's hallucinating. And I want sounds for that moment that she's hallucinating.. I don't know yet if I can make sound live, but it's a good possibility. Sorry for my english, I need to practice more! 

Answer (score 0):

Is there an actress onstage playing the hallucination or some other sort of visual cue for it? Or, do you have to sell it just with the FX?

Comment: Yes !! There's an actress on the stage